# Php Image upload failing and using imagecreatefromjpeg to process png and bmp files?

Tags: php, image, file, upload

Hello I have the following code to create a thumbnail of an image then upload it. The code is failing when I try to upload the image attached below and I don't know why. Previous to this code there is a main image upload which always works but the thumbnail script above works most of the time but not with the image attached for some reason. The code dies so the page outputs the success of the main image upload but the thumbnail never uploads and neither does the rest of the page.

Also will this code process images other than jpeg? If it won't how would I go about making it process other file types like bmp and png?

```
  // load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $upload_path . $filename );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );

  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_height = $thumbHeight;
  $new_width = floor( $width * ( $thumbHeight / $height ) );

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

  // save thumbnail into a file
  imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $upload_paththumbs . $filename );
```

[Image that fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bAx.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"the code is failing"*

Comment: Previous to this code there is a main image upload which always works but the thumbnail script above works most of the time but not with the image attached for some reason. The code dies so the page outputs the success of the main image upload but the thumbnail never uploads and neither does the rest of the page.

Comment: Sounds like you're not seeing the errors. Enable proper error reporting in your `php.ini` file with `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` and restart your web server

Comment: The 'php.ini' file is already configured as you say

Comment: Can you check for errors in the error log file for your web server? Without specific errors ... then the code is OK, maybe the parameters are wrong, so check all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with your image, so the problem must be with the set values of your input variables.

As already suggested in the comments, check your PHP error log.  If that doesn't show anything abnormal you'll need debug the code line-by-line.

For the second part of your question: no, your code won't work for images other than JPEG.  The changes, below, will handle GIF, JPEG, and PNG.

Note that the function `exif_imagetype()` might not be available by default. In this case you'll need to [activate the exif extension](http://php.net/manual/en/exif.installation.php) in your PHP config.

```
$upload_path = './';
$filename = 'b4bAx.jpg';
$upload_paththumbs = './thumb-';
$thumbHeight = 50;

switch ( exif_imagetype( $upload_path . $filename ) ) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        imagegif(
            thumb(imagecreatefromgif( $upload_path . $filename ), $thumbHeight),
            $upload_paththumbs . $filename
        );
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        imagejpeg(
            thumb(imagecreatefromjpeg( $upload_path . $filename ), $thumbHeight),
            $upload_paththumbs . $filename
        );
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        imagepng(
            thumb(imagecreatefrompng( $upload_path . $filename ), $thumbHeight),
            $upload_paththumbs . $filename
        );
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Unsupported image type!';
}

function thumb($img, $thumbHeight) {
    // get image size
    $width = imagesx( $img );
    $height = imagesy( $img );

    // calculate thumbnail size
    $new_height = $thumbHeight;
    $new_width = floor( $width * ( $thumbHeight / $height ) );

    // create a new temporary image
    $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

    // copy and resize old image into new image
    imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

    // return thumbnail
    return $tmp_img;
}
```